# Check it the Killing vectors satisfy Killing equation or not

Tags: general-relativity, research-level, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I am going through [Kerr/CFT correspondence paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4266) again, and I am at the section where authors specify [Killing vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) for near horizon extreme Kerr metric (shortly NHEK).

The metric is

$$d\bar{s}^2=2GJ\Omega^2\left(-(1+r^2)d\tau^2+\frac{dr^2}{1+r^2}+d\theta^2+\Lambda^2(d\varphi+rd\tau)^2\right)$$

Where

$$\Omega^2\equiv\frac{1+\cos^2\theta}{2},\quad\Lambda\equiv\frac{2\sin\theta}{1+\cos^2\theta}$$

It is said that the metric has enhanced $SL(2,\mathbb{R})\times U(1)$ isometry group. Now what exactly is enhanced symmetry? I only find mentioning of it in the context of string theory, so I'm not sure what to do with it.

If we ignore that for a moment, looking at the groups in question, $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ has 3 generators ($Sl(n,\mathbb{R})$ has $n^2-1$ elements), and $U(1)$ has one.

The rotational $U(1)$ symmetry is generated by Killing vector:

$$\xi_0=-\partial_\varphi$$

While time translations become part of an enhanced $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ isometry group generated by the Killing vectors

$$\xi_1=\frac{2r\sin\tau}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\partial_\tau-2\sqrt{1+r^2}\cos\tau\partial_r+\frac{2\sin\tau}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\partial_\varphi$$

$$\xi_2=-\frac{2r\cos\tau}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\partial_\tau-2\sqrt{1+r^2}\sin\tau\partial_r-\frac{2\cos\tau}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\partial_\varphi$$

$$\xi_3=2\partial_\tau$$

Now I wanted to try and find them, but that proved to be quite a challenge (I may try to do it in the end). So instead I wanted to check if they satisfy Killing equation. Another way of checking if they are Killing vectors is to check if [Lie derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) of the metric along the Killing vectors is 0

$$\mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\mu\nu}=\xi^\sigma\partial_\sigma g_{\mu\nu}+g_{\sigma\nu}\partial_\mu\xi^\sigma+g_{\mu\sigma}\partial_\nu\xi^\sigma=0$$

So I put the two simplest ones ($\xi_0$ and $\xi_3$), and they give 0 for each component. Nice.

I try with $\xi_2$, and I get non zero components.

So what is wrong with my interpretation?

I did the calculation by hand and with `RGTC` package in Mathematica, using `LieD` which calculates Lie derivative, and I made a code that calculates Killing equation, and still got non zero result.

---

### Edit

I'll write out what I get for $\tau\tau$ component.

So, my Killing vector $\xi_2$ has three nonzero components

$\xi^\tau=\frac{2r\sin\tau}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}$, $\xi^r=-2\sqrt{1+r^2}\cos\tau$, $\xi^\varphi=\frac{2\sin\tau}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}$

And the $\tau\tau$ part of Lie derivative is

$$\mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\tau\tau}=\xi^\sigma\partial_\sigma g_{\tau\tau}+g_{\sigma\tau}\partial_\tau\xi^\sigma+g_{\tau\sigma}\partial_\tau\xi^\sigma$$

Only nonzero metric components that can be used are $g_{\tau\tau}$, and $g_{\tau\varphi}=g_{\varphi\tau}$.

They are

$$g_{\tau\tau}=-2GJ\Omega(\theta)^2(1+r^2(1-\Lambda(\theta)^2))$$

$$g_{\varphi\tau}=4GJr\Omega(\theta)^2\Lambda(\theta)^2$$

So, for the first part of Lie derivative, since $g_{\tau\tau}$ depends only on $r$ and $\theta$ my $\xi^\sigma$ is only $\xi^r$, since $\xi^\theta=0$. And the second part we have 2 times the ($g_{\tau\tau}\partial_\tau\xi^\tau+g_{\varphi\tau}\partial_\tau\xi^\varphi$).
Which, after some simplifying becomes

$$\mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\tau\tau}=\frac{8 G J r \Lambda (\theta )^2 \Omega (\theta )^2 \cos (\tau )}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}$$

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't think this question is considered as "homework", since it (1) arose from reading a research paper and (2) it isn't *exactly* about solving a problem, .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

About the symmetry, the part : $-(1+r^2)d\tau^2+\frac{dr^2}{1+r^2}$ is just the metrics of [AdS2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space#Coordinate_patches), so there is a $SO(2,1)$ symmetry.

At fixed $\theta$, we have this $SO(2,1) \sim SL(2,R)$ symmetry plus the $U(1)$ symmetry corresponding to the invariance by $\phi$ translation.

The $\theta$ parameters are playing the role of geometrical terms, but do not change the nature of the symmetry.

[Ref](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905099), Chapter 2, page 3

[EDIT]

Correcting OP calculus:

$\mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\tau\tau}=\xi^\sigma\partial_\sigma g_{\tau\tau}+g_{\sigma\tau}\partial_\tau\xi^\sigma+g_{\tau\sigma}\partial_\tau\xi^\sigma \tag{1}$

$g_{\tau\tau}$ depends only on $r$, and the only non-null metrics $g_{\sigma\tau} =g_{\tau\sigma}$,are $g_{\tau\tau},g_{\tau\varphi} =g_{\varphi\tau}$, so finally :

$\mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\tau\tau}=\xi^r\partial_r g_{\tau\tau}+ 2(g_{\tau\tau}\partial_\tau\xi^\tau+g_{\tau\varphi}\partial_\tau\xi^\varphi )\tag{2}$

The first term is equal to :

$$\xi^r\partial_r g_{\tau\tau} = [2 GJ \Omega^2][-2\sqrt{1+r^2}\cos\tau][2(\Lambda^2-1)r]\tag{3}$$

The second term is equal to :

$$2g_{\tau\tau}\partial_\tau\xi^\tau = [2 GJ \Omega^2]2[-1 +(\Lambda^2-1)r^2][\frac{2r\cos\tau}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}]\tag{4}$$

The third term is equal to :

$$2g_{\tau\varphi}\partial_\tau\xi^\varphi = [2 GJ \Omega^2]2[\Lambda^2r][\frac{2\cos\tau}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}]\tag{5}$$

Finally we have :

$$\mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\tau\tau}= \\ \frac{(8 GJ \Omega^2)(r \cos\tau)}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}[-(1+r^2)(\Lambda^2-1)+(-1 +(\Lambda^2-1)r^2)+ \Lambda^2]=0\tag{6}$$

Comment: So that's the 'enhancing' part?

Comment: $SL(2,R) * U(1)$ is not the symmetry of the standard Kerr metrics, it is only correct near horizon, so one says, that, near horizon, there is an "enhanced" symmetry, which is greater than the standard symmetry for the Kerr metrics.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now :) I'll read the part about Killing vectors in that paper too, maybe there will be an answer there about the second part :) Thanks

Comment: For which $\mu, \nu$, do you get a non-zero result for $\mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\mu\nu}$ ?

Comment: When using $\xi_2$ I have nonzero: $\tau\tau$, $\tau r$ $\tau\varphi$, $r\tau$, $r\varphi$ and $\varphi\tau$, $\varphi r$

Comment: By symmetry, you have only $\tau \tau, \tau \phi, r \tau, r \phi$

Comment: Yes, the expressions are the same on those. But still nonzero.

Comment: Could it be that they are nonzero because they're conformal Killing fields?

Comment: I found zero for $ \mu \nu = \tau \tau$, could you edit  your question with your calculus for these indices. Thanks. I have to leave now, but I will look at your result tomorrow.

Comment: But how? $\Omega$ and $\Lambda$ are a part of the metric, and they depend on $\theta$ :S

Comment: So ?  I don't understand you remark.

Comment: Or do I need to go back to the article and say that we are interested in asymptotic region, and then take $\theta$ as constant?

Comment: Oh, wait... I messed sth up. Disregard that comment.

Comment: In the expression of $\mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\tau\tau}$, there is no derivation relatively to $\theta$, so every expression depending on $\theta$ could be considered as a scalar in the derivation operation.

Comment: No, I got that, I looked at the wrong derivation. I put derivation $\partial_\phi$ for some reason. I need to go back and do it again. I'll go carefully through it all and get back with what I've got. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I think you forgot an extra 2 in the $g_{\tau\varphi}$ part of the metric. $2g_{\tau\varphi}\partial_\tau\xi^\phi$ is equal to $2\cdot(4GJ\Omega^2)(r^2\Lambda^2)\frac{2\cos\tau}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}$ :\

Comment: $g_{\tau\varphi} = g_{\varphi\tau} = \Lambda^2 r$

Comment: No, it's $(2GJ\Omega^2)(2r\Lambda^2)$, since you have $\Lambda^2(d\varphi+rd\tau)^2=\Lambda(d\varphi^2+2r d\varphi d\tau+r^2 d\tau^2)$

Comment: No, the metrics is $(ds^2 = \Lambda^2 r d\varphi d\tau + \Lambda^2 r d\tau d\varphi )+...$

Comment: ...That is $ds^2 = g_{\varphi\tau} d\varphi d\tau +g_{\tau\varphi} d\tau d\varphi + ...$

Comment: I thought that I can just write it like normal quadratic expansion, and say that those two are equal. I guess I was dead wrong :\ Thanks for the clarification, this will help me immensely.